# Use Apache 1.3 module with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, oc4j

I have been asked to try to upgrade an installation of Apache 1.3 to a supported release, i.e. to Apache 2.4.53 on Solaris

My current sticking-point is that Apache is supposed to hand off some requests to a secondary application, with the help of  `mod_oc4j.so`

I'm not much of a Solaris expert, but I'm wondering why that module works in 1.3 but gives me: `Cannot load ....libexec/mod_oc4j.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: fatal: relocation error: file ..../mod_oc4j.so: symbol ap_null_cleanup: referenced symbol not found`  in 2.4? And of course, what if anything can I do about it?

Comment: My experience with Oracle products is that you typically need to install their massive application server. Copying a library file on top of regular Apache HTTP Server is probably not a scenario they ever conceived. (I don't have first hand experience with OC4J, but I thought it'd share my thoughts given the lack of answers so far).